# Using ngRoute with AngularJS Errors

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm creating an app using Meteor as my framework and AngularJS on the front end. I've been stuck on attempting to figure out how to route my website. What I was planning of doing is breaking up my HTML into separate files so its easier to make changes in the future and its also organized.

This is my JS file :

```
var myApp = angular.module('CalorieCounter',['angular-meteor']);
angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

myApp.config(['$routeProvider',function($routeProvider) {
   $routeProvider
   .when('/', {
     templateUrl : 'main.html',
     controller : 'formCtrl'
   });
});
```

The error I'm receiving is the following :

```
angular_angular.js?hash=08f63d2…:83 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] 
Failed to instantiate module CalorieCounter due to:
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $routeProvider
```

Not sure why exactly I'm receiving this error...I literally followed a tutorial that I found online. Please advise. Anyone. Been stuck on this for the past 4 hours :(

**UPDATE #1**

After, following what everyone suggested, now I'm getting the following error:

```
angular_angular.js?hash=08f63d2…:83 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]    
Failed to instantiate module CalorieCounter due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ngRoute due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ngRoute' is not available! You either    
misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module   
ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument
```

I don't understand why I'm getting this error, when I just checked up with the AngularJS Docs : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute

**UPDATE #2**

I figured out what was wrong and do not have the error reported in Update #1. What I'm confused about now is the following :

```
myApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider
 .when('/', {
  templateUrl : 'main.html',
  controller : 'formCtrl'
 })

 .when('/register', {
  templateUrl : 'public/register.html'
 });
});
```

When I try to go to : localhost:3000/register it just refreshes the home page and stays there. Another question, in my HTML files, how do I redirect my button to the specified HTML file? Is that just regular HTML convention or is there a specific way of doing it in terms of AngularJS?

Comment: dude if you want us to write your program, we will charge you. Please look at the documentation for ng-route before asking a question like update #2

Comment: Tbh, I'm not asking you to write my program. I've been looking at it for the past 4 hours...which is why I thought a new set of eyes might be able to catch something that I clearly can't see. If you don't want to help, its cool. You don't need to. Thank you for all your help though! Have a great day!

Comment: If anyone does feel like I'm doing that, please feel free to delete my question. My intention was not that, I just needed some help w/understanding what is going wrong w/my code. Thank you for all who have helped! Really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

you're creating 2 angular modules. It's confusing because the CalorieCounter module is called 'myApp', and the 'myApp' module is not assigned to any var. To use the CalorieCounter module within the myApp module, add it as a dependency:

```
var calorieCounterApp = angular.module('CalorieCounter',['angular-meteor']);
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'calorieCounterApp']);

myApp.config(['$routeProvider',function($routeProvider) {
   $routeProvider
   .when('/', {
     templateUrl : 'main.html',
     controller : 'formCtrl'
   });
});
```

Comment: Used you're suggestion, please look at updated portion. Thanks for the help tho! Really appreciate it!

Comment: have you inserted the angular-route.js script? It's a separate script.

Comment: Update #1 has fixed, please look at Update #2. Thanks for the help! Really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Change to this:

```
var myApp = angular.module('CalorieCounter',['angular-meteor','ngRoute']);
```

Comment: Used you're suggestion, please look at updated portion. Thanks for the help tho! Really appreciate it!

Comment: use js file for ngRoute before the file that refrence angular.module

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that you're declaring `ngRoute` on the module `myApp`, but the module you're referring to through the `myApp` **variable** is `CalorieCounter`

If you change it to this it should work:

```
var myApp = angular.module('CalorieCounter',['angular-meteor', 'ngRoute']);
```

Comment: Used you're suggestion, please look at updated portion. Thanks for the help tho! Really appreciate it!

Comment: @halapgos1 Are you loading the ngRoute files in your index BEFORE angular ? If not, that's the problem

Comment: Update #1 has fixed, please look at Update #2. Thanks for the help! Really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about `ngRoute` but you can use [`angularui:angular-ui-router`](https://atmospherejs.com/angularui/angular-ui-router) ([github](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router)) package to route your website like this (Code from the example in documentation),

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [
    'angular-meteor',
    'ui.router'
]);

myApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    // For any unmatched url, redirect to /state1
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/state1");

    // Now set up the states
    $stateProvider
    .state('state1', {
        url: "/state1",
        templateUrl: "partials/state1.html"
    })
    .state('state1.list', {
        url: "/list",
        templateUrl: "partials/state1.list.html",
        controller: function($scope) {
            $scope.items = ["A", "List", "Of", "Items"];
        }
    })
    .state('state2', {
        url: "/state2",
        templateUrl: "partials/state2.html"
    })
    .state('state2.list', {
        url: "/list",
        templateUrl: "partials/state2.list.html",
        controller: function($scope) {
            $scope.things = ["A", "Set", "Of", "Things"];
        }
    });
});
```